# Facebook asking write permissions

Tags: android, facebook

I've encountered a problem. During login I ask read permissions, that seems to work fine, but whenever I want to share something I use this method to check for required permissions:

```
public interface OnWritePermissionListener {
    public void result(boolean success);
}

public void askWritePermissions(final OnWritePermissionListener listener) {
    if (!getSession().getPermissions().containsAll(writePermissions)) {
        L.d("Requesting write permissions.");
        Session.NewPermissionsRequest newPermissionsRequest = new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(activity, writePermissions);
        newPermissionsRequest.setCallback(new StatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
                L.d("Status callback for askWritePermissions. State: %s. Exception: %s.", state.name(), exception == null ? "none" : exception.toString());
                if (session.getPermissions().containsAll(writePermissions)) {
                    listener.result(true);
                } else {
                    listener.result(false);
                }
            }
        });
        getSession().requestNewPublishPermissions(newPermissionsRequest);
    } else {
        L.d("Write permissions already granted.");
        listener.result(true);
    }
    return;
}
```

writePermissions contains string entry: "publish_actions"

The problem is that when I call this method the FB window appears only for a half second and then dissapears calling listener.result(false). Log shows this:

```
Status callback for askWritePermissions. State: OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED. Exception: none.
```

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?